# Graph Api - manage multiple Facebook accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question about Graph Api from Facebook. We want to create tool to management accounts in facebook and groups releated with them.

Basic functionality of tool is possibility to add acounts to the system, and then add you can add multiple facebook accounts to each of them. Then, system get all posts from groups releated with facebook accounts.

I did research, and I know quite what is possible and what no, but many endpoints of API requires app review. My question is about this review - wheater app like that, when one user can add multiple facebook accouns and use data (like posts, comments) from them is allowed by facebook and will pass the review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what exactly you mean by “accounts” …

Facebook pages? Sure, you can let your app user add as many of those as they like, for the purpose of managing them, reading feed data, etc.

User profiles? That would not really make sense, because every person is only allowed to have one personal profile on the platform to begin with. And adding *other* people’s profiles (by having them authorize your app, using their access tokens on behalf of someone else) is likely not going to fly in review either.

> when one user can add multiple facebook accouns and use data (like posts, comments) from them is allowed by facebook

“Using data” is rather vague as well; what you can and can’t do with user data is outlined in the Platform Policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I supposed that with multiple Facebook acounts assigned to one account in the system might be problematic. But the reality is, for example in recruitements agency that people use many Facebook accounts. In my purpose I want to organize posts from groups releated with these accounts in one place - in the system.

Comment: That might be, but is not going to change what Facebook allows and doesn’t allow in review.

Comment: I get it, but in this policy I didn't see information about multiple Facebook accounts releated with one account in the system. How would you rate the chance to accept application like that?

Comment: I think you would only be able to get this through review if you basically _cheat_ - and present them a version of your app, that deals with the one genuine personal profile of your app user only. But I would not recommend that - if someone reports your app for this, or they do an random re-check of your app later, it will most likely be disabled. And even your general ability to develop apps on the platform coulöd be taken away.

Comment: Thank you again. I have to think it over again.